# iPad javascript engine ? table rendering flicker

Tags: javascript, ipad

I experience a "flicker" (not instant rendering/update) when using simple `replaceChild` in a table update on the iPad.

Table contains at most 100 rows but this behavior starts at 35 rows on the (iPad 1)

### code simplified

```
tbl = document.getElementById('table1');
tbl_fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(); // contains the rows and cells

tbody = document.createElement("tbody");        
tbody.appendChild(tbl_fragment);

old_tbody = tbl.tBodies[0];

tbl.replaceChild(tbody, old_tbody);
```

Comment: Could you more specifically explain "flicker" ?

Comment: it isn't instant ... the table disappear for 1/4 of a sec (not long but noticable) before the new content is visible.